# Get Tab ID of Calling Extension Page / chrome.tabs.close on Self

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to get the tab ID of the caller? Or is there a way to use chrome.tabs.remove on the calling tab without an id?

Edit: Found how to get tab id: chrome.tabs.getCurrent

However, that also does not bypass the close dialog.

Comment: Define "caller". A `sendMessage` from a content script?

Comment: No, a page packaged inside the extension.

Answer (score 1):

To close itself, an extension page does not need to call Chrome API.

Good old `window.close()` works.

Comment: That would, but the page asks the user to confirm closing with beforeunload event, but I need to close the page silently in the background.

Comment: I do not understand the question. You said "page packaged inside the extension". That means you fully control it. Remove the confirmation before closing.. Besides, I don't think `chrome.tabs.remove` bypasses that.

Comment: I thought it did bypass it, that was why I asked